# HTML password field returning none via POST request

Tags: django, django-views

On submitting password field is showing none while as confirm password is working fine, don't know where I am wrong in this, tried changing name attribute doesn't work. The other fields are working fine only issue is with password field.

```
    <form action="" method="POST">  
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col form-group">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                <div class="col form-group">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
            </div> <!-- form-row end.// -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                <small class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input name="gender" class="custom-control-input" checked="" type="radio" name="gender" value="option1">
                  <span class="custom-control-label"> Male </span>
                </label>
                <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input name="gender" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="gender" value="option2">
                  <span class="custom-control-label"> Female </span>
                </label>
            </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <select name="city" id="inputState" class="form-control">
                      <option> Choose...</option>
                        {% for val in city %}
                        <option value="{{val.city_name }}">{{val.city_name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                 
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label>Country</label>
                  <select name="country" id="inputState" class="form-control">
                    <option> Choose...</option>
                      <option>Uzbekistan</option>
                      <option>Russia</option>
                      <option selected="">United States</option>
                      <option>India</option>
                      <option>Afganistan</option>
                  </select>
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
            </div> <!-- form-row.// -->
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label>Mobile number</label>
                  <input name="mob_number" type="tel" class="form-control">
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                
            </div> <!-- form-row.// -->
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Create password</label>
                    <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password">
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// --> 
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Repeat password</label>
                    <input name="confirm_password" class="form-control" type="password">
                </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Register  </button>
            </div> <!-- form-group// -->      
                
        </form>
```

**my view**

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    city = City.objects.all()
    if request.method== 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        print(email)
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        print(country)
        password = request.POST.get('password') <-- this returns None
        conf_password = request.POST.get('confirm_password')
        contact_no = request.POST.get('mob_number')
        print(conf_password,password)
        if password != conf_password:
            messages.add_message(request,messages.ERROR,'passwords does not match kindl re-enter')
            return redirect('/register')
        else:
            username = email.split('@')[0]
            print(username)
            user= User(username=username,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email)  
            user.set_password(password)  
            user.save()       
            customer=Customers(user=user,contact_no=contact_no,city=city,gender=gender)
            customer.save()
            return redirect('/')

    return render(request,'register.html',{
        'city':city
    } )
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: `password = request.POST.get('password')` this is giving me `None` value even though i am entering password

Comment: Please provide your complete `form` code, at least `submit` and `form action attribute` parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSRF token like belows: If still the same problem, then provide the full code related to form.

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
          {% csrf_token %} -----> Use CSRF token Here...
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col form-group">
                            <label>First name</label>
                            <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" 
                            placeholder="">
        </form>
```